# Command `yarn jest` failed

Tags: nearprotocol, near, nearprotocol-validator

I'm learning Near with 'Guide to Cross-contract Calls'.
(https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/contracts/cross-contract-calls)

In step 1, I got [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpfFe.png) in a new command prompt when I typed `yarn jest`.

How can I figure it out?

Comment: I can't upload image directly. When I try drag&drop the image, only got a massage is
`You're not allowed to embed images in your posts yet, so we've included a link instead.As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed images.`

Comment: Are you sure your installation is in a good condition? By a quick look at the image, It seems it cannot find a file that should be part of it.

Comment: I got an answer from Near that it was an outdated code. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question with the solution you have found and that might help future readers!